# How to securely log user statistics

Tags: javascript, security, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

For a quiz I made, I have a firebase endpoint I'm writing to so that I can record user's results for analysis. However, I am having a hard time figuring out a way to secure my endpoint from malicious data inserts.

My problem is: since there's no login involved, **how do I make sure only my web app (the quiz) can write to the endpoint?**

The solution doesn't have to be specific to firebase.

An additional challenge is that the quiz is hosted on github so all the code is public, but that can be changed if needed. But bonus points if someone can provide a solution that can keep my code hosted on github!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is: since there's no login involved, how do I make sure
>   only my web app (the quiz) can write to the endpoint?

Simple answer: you can't.

As long as you have an API that doesn't require any kind of authentication then anybody (with sufficient knowledge of how the web works) will be capable of forging an HTTP request to it. So you'd better start thinking of some mechanism for authenticating/tracking your users if you want to be able to protect your API against malicious use.

Comment: Hm how do web analytics services like google analytics monitor user behavior then? Or is that something completely different?

Comment: Google Analytics use cookies to track user behavior. But a sufficiently determined malicious user could forge any HTTP request you can imagine and fake those results. So, the only way to provide absolute security for this information is to authenticate your users.

Comment: Note that even when you authenticate the user, you have no way of ensuring that it's you app accessing the Firebase backend. You only know what user is accessing the data.